# Is Lich Bane viable on Amumu?

Tags: league-of-legends

**Is Lich Bane viable on Amumu (jungle)** (for ranked/competitive)?

Pros:

1. You get some **movement speed**, which is great for chasing enemies
2. You get **ability power**, which increases your overall damage output
3. You can get an autoattack off after you hit your Q which procs **spellblade**.
4. E has a pretty low cooldown even if you're not getting hit, which lets you get some spellblade procs pretty often
5. Higher single target damage which allows faster baron and dragon clear
6. The mana is nice

Cons:

1. You're **melee**, which makes it harder to hit with autoattacks
2. The other items you build are normally tanky (Sunfire, Liandrys, Abyssal, Zhonya's)

It might make it more viable in lategame, when you're winning and you sell your boots or your Jungler item for it.

[My Runes (Ap mixed + armor)](http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/56793435#runes)

- Ability Power + 14.9
- Ability Power / Level +1.56 (28.04 @ 18)
- Armor + 9
- Magic Pen. + 7.8

[My Masteries (MuMu)](http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/56793435#masteries) 9/21/0

Comment: Pretty much ANY AP item on him is better than lich bane to be honest although I'd never build him heavy HP to begin with.

Comment: @dphil disagree: ardent censer, frost queen.... AP items i would never even consider byuing on him ;-)

Comment: I don't consider those AP items TBH.  Splashing some AP in with some other effects don't make them AP items.  Those are more utility items or gold income.  They are no more AP items than Lliandry's is a tank item.

Comment: could the downvoter give me some feedback? thinking the item is not viable is not a downvote reason

Comment: @PhilippSander You always have to have to expect downvotes when asking a Viability question. A lot of people like them but there are [some who dislike them](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9747/are-questions-about-item-viablility-allowed). While I don't see a problem in this question, maybe someone else does (downvotes aren't evil ;) maybe someone doesn't like your build or it's something completely different).

Answer (score 3):

It definitely shouldn't be your first choice. The main Problem with Lichbane is that you require some AP for it to be efficient. Of course, if you are playing AP Amumu you could definitely say that it's a good and viable Item, however the viability of Full AP Amumu is rather questionable.

If you want to go for a bit of extra damage on Amumu or other low-scaling AP/Magic damage tanks in general like sejuani your best choices would be items like Liandrys Torment, Abyssal Scepter or sometimes even Zhonyas or Rylais Crystal Scepter. All of these items provide either enough Abilitypower or Magic penetration to increse your damageoutput by a good amount and they also Provide either Health, Armor or Magic resistance.

The main function of Amumu in a teamfight is bringing a lot of CC and a little bit of sustained damage while soaking up as much damage as possible. If you want to play an AP Assassin Amumu you will of course be able to oneshot ADCs (the scaling on your Q and Ult are pretty decent) but in general you should have enough burst in your team from mid or toplane. Amumus damage potential lies in low sustained damage, not in average burst damage.

Comment: +1 fully agree! but what about the idea to sell boots or jungler item and replace it with lich bane?

Comment: @PhilippSander you should never sell your boots in lategame. You could get caught and you could also miss a chance on catching someone (the 5% movementspeed are not as good as upgraded boots). And the tank jungle Item is extremely strong in lategame so I wouldn't recommend selling it.

Comment: i'm always buying the AP jungler item. tank jungle doesnt seem to work in my elo (did 3 games with it)... i should try it

Comment: My absolute favorite item on amumu is Iceborne Gauntlet. It synergizes really well with his E and gives him the mana, cdr, and armor he needs. If you're concerned about movement, run ms quints (I do and love it) because amumu has really good base damage. I also use mobis, but sell them for merc treads/ninja tabi if it goes to late game.

Comment: @slow_excellence you have a weird amumu build :D

Comment: One other small thing to remember with AP Amumu is that you preferably want to auto attack them BEFORE you cast any spells to lower their MR for your spells. Lich Bane needs the auto attack to be after a spell. You can always auto attack more than once, so it's not a big deal, but still a small little detail to be mindful of.

Comment: @Philipp Sander - it is strange but it is also extremely successful :p I picked it up off a friend of mine who mains amumu and it makes all the difference. The mobis/ms quints allow you to gank more often and stick better while golem/iceborne give you that early game tankiness required to dive opponents. From there its situational, but I usually wind up getting sunfires and abyssal if my team is ahead. Randuins and banshees are also great items on him. Just remember, more tanky = more time to lay damage down/soak up damage that your carries would be receiving.

Comment: @slow_excellence could you give me a link to the full build? i want to try it :)

Comment: @Philipp Sander - I don't have a link to the build anywhere atm unfortunately. I use my ["Mumbu Jangru" runes and "Amu Jinglejanglejongle" masteries](http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/31476489#runes). The build is pretty much as follows: Rush Jungle item; finish mobis; if its still fairly early then build sheen, otherwise grab giants belt; if you got sheen, finish iceborne ASAP; after iceborne,  build randuins/sunfire; grab abyssal if your team is ahead, banshees if not. Try to build to counter who is fed the most (armor for ad, mr for ap). Also, add in liandrys if your team is super fed!